# Rvest loop breaks on redirecting site

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping, vectorization, rvest

My situation: I have a long (20k lines) list of URLs that I need to scrape particular data elements from for an analysis. For the purpose of this example, I'm looking for a particular field called "sol-num", which the the solicitation number. Using the following function, I can fetch the solicitation number for any procurement listed on FedBizOpps:

```
require(rvest)
require(magrittr)
fetchSolNum<-function(URL){
  URL<-as.character(URL)
  solNum<-html(URL)%>%
    html_node(".sol-num")%>%
    html_text()
}
```

Now, I have a list of thousands of URLs, and I want to pull the solicitation number for each one, depositing it into a new column on the data frame from which I got the list of URLs. For your own testing, here is the first ten lines in the list of URLs:

```
list<-c("https://www.fbo.gov/spg/DISA/D4AD/DITCO/HC1028-12-T-0025/listing.html",
"https://www.fbo.gov/notices/c360b067077aabde331d66e0fe2d1f8f",         
"https://www.fbo.gov/notices/f63053a7a6e858a5b7b537a660c473b7",         
"https://www.fbo.gov/spg/DLA/J3/DSCP-I/SPM300-12-R-0024/listing.html",  
"https://www.fbo.gov/spg/DLA/J3/DAPS/SP7000-11-Q-0047/listing.html",    
"https://www.fbo.gov/spg/USAF/AFMC/OCALCCC/F3YCDW1245A001/listing.html",
"https://www.fbo.gov/spg/USAF/AFMC/AFFTC/FA9300-12-R-5001/listing.html",
"https://www.fbo.gov/notices/17ddec6ae37feb69704b1a52e22eeb26",         
"https://www.fbo.gov/notices/3b76d40705a23a749aad46df88dcee0c",         
"https://www.fbo.gov/notices/91873b727968dc664ada76c48e53e4df") 
raw <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(list), nrow=10, byrow=T))
```

I want to store the output in the variable `solNum` in my data frame called `raw`, so my function right now has been to use a loop:

```
raw$solNum<-0

j=1
for (i in list){
  raw$solNum[j]<-fetchSolNum(i)
  j=j+1
}
```

Running the code currently deposits values for the top five rows, then returns the following error:

```
 Error in xml_apply(x, XML::xmlValue, ..., .type = character(1)) : 
  Unknown input of class: NULL
```

Upon further investigation, I have found out that the problem likely lies in the fact that this URL from the list: https://www.fbo.gov/spg/USAF/AFMC/OCALCCC/F3YCDW1245A001/listing.html goes to a sort of disambiguation page, since there are two procurements with this URL.

Considering that my full list is 20k lines long, I don't have the time to go through and clean the list of all the invalid URLs. Is there a way to have my current function just insert an NA value for lines where the URL is invalid or something like that? How can I get it to not break on this error?

Also, reading around tells me that it may be faster and more efficient to have this operation run as a vectorized function rather than a loop. Could anyone lend any tips on what that might look like in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably just a `tryCatch()` would work here to catch the error and give NA instead. As far as vectorization, I doubt you'd see any real gains. It takes a while (a second or two sometimes) to read a website. With 20K of them, it's gonna take some time. Definitely check out Hadley's chapter on exceptions and debugging and set up some checking in your code so it doesn't bomb out 4 hours into running... http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html